# GTM event working but is not showing in Google Analytics Events, why?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I add the Tag Manager code and Google Analytics code on my website.

in tag manager, I create a Button click event. And It's working in Tag manager preview mode but not showing in Google Analytics real-time events.

[image]

Here What my tag look like

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine what I missed is I didn't add the correct Google Analytics ID

Comment: Yeah that will do it!